# Why are Arabic and Chinese characters rendered correctly even without using meta charset="utf-8"?

Tags: html, utf-8

I am very new to HTML. Recently I encountered the `<meta charset="utf-8>"` tag which ensures letters and characters are rendered properly in a browser.

But I was wondering why even if I do not specify UTF-8 all letters and characters are displayed perfectly anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page you're sending to the browser uses a specific character encoding (e.g. UTF-8). The browser must interpret the page in the correct encoding to read it correctly (i.e. as intended) and display the correct characters. There are several ways in which the browser determines what encoding to use, which it falls back to successively:

1. HTTP `Content-Type` header
2. HTML meta tags
3. any built-in heuristics
4. the browser/system default encoding

If the page displays correctly without an HTML meta tag, that means one of the other mechanisms caused the browser to choose to interpret the page as UTF-8. Probably your web server is outputting an HTTP `Content-Type` header, or your browser/system's default is UTF-8.

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation it was quite helpful :)

Comment: Sorry, dude one last question. So, as UTF-8 is a default character set, it means I can omit it completely in future projects? I hope you will answer:)

Comment: No, you should always annotate your pages with the charset that is used, both in HTTP headers and HTML meta tags (the latter for if you work with the HTML offline without an HTTP server involved for whatever reason). You must not leave the selection of the charset up to chance/implicit defaults. Explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the [default character encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp) for HTML5 is UTF-8.

See also [this documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/):

> **The default character-set for HTML5 is UTF-8.**
>
> Example `<meta charset="UTF-8">`
>
> The Unicode Consortium developed the UTF-8 and UTF-16 standards,
> because the ISO-8859 character-sets are limited, and not compatible a multilingual environment.
>
> The Unicode Standard covers (almost) all the characters, punctuations, and symbols in the world.
>
> All HTML5 and XML processors support UTF-8, UTF-16, Windows-1252, and
> ISO-8859.

**EDIT** fun facts: The documentation changed over time:

- "For HTML5, the default character encoding is UTF-8." ([2017-01-16](https://web.archive.org/web/20170116172606/https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/))
- "The HTML5 specification encourages web developers to use the UTF-8 character set!" ([2021-01-14](https://web.archive.org/web/20210114074202/https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/))
- "All modern computer languages use the UTF-8 character set a sdefault. [sic!]" ([2023-09-30](https://web.archive.org/web/20230930053941/https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/))

For me, this indicates that you [really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51928040/why-are-arabic-and-chinese-characters-rendered-correctly-even-without-using-meta/51928134#comment90806289_51928118) should always annotate your pages with the character set that is used. In addition, the latest documentation is more explicit about that:

> To display an HTML page correctly, the browser must know what character set (encoding) to use

Comment: thank you for your attention and solution now I got the point :)